# special characters in batch file

Tags: audio, batch

I downloaded Audio Device Switcher from Microsoft Store in order to quickly change audio device.

Switching device inside the tool works well, however when I try to save command in batch file, I get error message for one of my devices as it's name contains special character (`AudioDeviceSwitcher "Microphone Array (Intel® Smart Sound Technology (Intel® SST)) / 2471096937" -recording`)

What I tried:

- above command works well inside the tool itself, or when I copy it to command or powershell window
- it doesn't work if I copy the command into notepad / notepad++ and save it as .bat or .ps1. Although I see the command correctly in the editor, when I run it, it gets corrupted.

Is there any way to fix it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could be a Code Page issue - [CHCP - Change Code Page - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html). Does it work in PowerShell?

Comment: @DavidPostill changing codepage to UTF-8 at the beginning of batch file solved the issue. Thanks! Please post it as an answer so I'll be able to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I get error message for one of my devices as it's name contains special character

> (AudioDeviceSwitcher "Microphone Array (Intel® Smart Sound Technology (Intel® SST)) / 2471096937" -recording)

Your device name contains Unicode characters (`®`). If you set the Code Page appropriately at the start of your batch file your code should work.

Example:

```
chcp UTF-8
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Chcp - Change Code Page - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html)